# Modifying OpenNI Kinect plugin to get back disparity data again? gazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[`https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/browser/stacks/simulator_gazebo/trunk/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_openni_kinect.cpp`](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/browser/stacks/simulator_gazebo/trunk/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_openni_kinect.cpp)

Hi all,

I thought this was the most appropriate place to post this.

If you look at the above plugin, the functionality to return disparity data was removed, as opposed to the deprecated driver. 
** How can I modify this plugin to return disparity data?  
I'm happy to help, I just don't understand what the blocker is.

Alternatively, can I run some processing nodes on ROS to generate disparity data?

Cheers, 
David.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/787/modifying-openni-kinect-plugin-to-get-back-disparity-data-again?-gazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so/) by [dbworth](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/144/dbworth/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We are moving towards running gazebo as a system install against ROS.  Gazebo ROS plugins developments have been moved to [gazebo_ros_pkgs](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs) repository, you can find corresponding [gazebo_ros_openni_kinect.cpp source here](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/hydro-devel/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_openni_kinect.cpp).  For reference, please take a look at [tutorial on installing gazebo_ros_pkgs](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Installing_gazebo_ros_Packages) and the [How to Contribute Page](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/hydro-devel/CONTRIBUTING.md).  Please start by [filing an issue on the issue tracker](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues).  And possibly followed by [creating a pull request with patch fix in your branch](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/pulls)? Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0